# Python, parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to pull out the 'transcript' section from the below JSON example with the following code. However, I must be doing something incorrectly, as it isn't working.

```
jsonText=str(jsonText)
parsedJson=json.loads(jsonText)
transcript=""
try:
    resultsList=parsedJson['results']
    for i in range(0, len(resultsList)):
        transcript+=parsedJson['results'][i]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
except:
    Logger.printLine("Watson did not return any proper results. "+str(parsedJson), 3)
return transcript
```

And, my results when run- which shows the json is being received from API and loaded with json.loads, so my error must be with my for loop in my try: statement I'm assuming:

```
2021-6-25 10:23:38 [ERROR]: Watson did not return any proper results.
{
   "result":{
      "result_index":0,
      "results":[
         {
            "final":true,
            "alternatives":[
               {
                  "transcript":"hi I am calling to speak with so and so- blah blah blah this is the part I'm trying to pull from the json.",
                  "confidence":0.94
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you take the for loop out of the `try, except` block and post the actual error that is returned.

Comment: Something like `print(''.join(i["alternatives"][0]["transcript"] for i in parsedJson['result']['results']))`? Also, if you want to see where your actual error is happening, don't hide it with a bare `except`.

Comment: You aren't starting with the top level key. You should try: `resultsList=parsedJson['result']['results']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output you included, it looks like your parsedJson object has a key `result` but you are trying to use the key `results`.

Try this instead:

```
resultsList = parsedJson['result']['results']
for i in range(0, len(resultsList)):
        transcript+=parsedJson['result']['results'][i]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
```

Comment: This makes the issue "caused by a typo", no? Questions in that category should be closed as off-topic, not answered. See #2 in the list of still-off-topic categories at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Add to your **try** statement Exception you're catching. The exception message will show you where is the problem

```
    try:
        resultsList=parsedJson['results']
        for i in range(0, len(resultsList)):
            transcript+=parsedJson['results'][i]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
    except Exception as e:
        Logger.printLine(e)
        Logger.printLine("Watson did not return any proper results. "+str(parsedJson), 3)
    return transcript
```